# Excel VBA to send click to JavaScript link

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, hyperlink

I have a webpage with:

```js
<td onclick="window.location.href='search_generate.php?listType=salesCurrentMyOfficeRS&amp;referer=bWFpbi5waHA/';" colspan="2">Sales current</td>
```

I have been unable to find a way to send a click as there is no class name, id or tag.

Can someone suggest a solution, please? A text search to find 'Sales Current' would be an idea, but again I could not find a way to achieve this. The text is unique on the page.

The code around the function is:

```html
<table class="dashboardBorderTop dashboardGroup" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <tbody><tr>
      <td onclick="window.location.href='search_generate.php?listType=salesCurrentMyOfficeRS&amp;referer=bWFpbi5waHA/';" colspan="2">Sales current</td>
      <td onclick="window.location.href='search_generate.php?listType=salesCurrentMyOfficeRS&amp;referer=bWFpbi5waHA/';" width="20" class="dashboardAmount">260</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td onclick="window.location.href='search_generate.php?listType=salesExchangedMyOfficeRS&amp;referer=bWFpbi5waHA/';" colspan="2">Sales exchanged</td>
      <td onclick="window.location.href='search_generate.php?listType=salesExchangedMyOfficeRS&amp;referer=bWFpbi5waHA/';" width="20" class="dashboardAmount">20</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you share some code

Comment: Is there any parent div or element? Which should have unique `ID` or class ?

Comment: Thanks Mr.Developer I have just posted some more code around the link.

Comment: do you have the webpage link to share or is it internal?

Comment: QHarr it is our custom CRM so can't really give a URL. Sorry!

Comment: can you get elements by tag name (td) iterate over until text = Sales current then .Click on that element?

Comment: QHarr, yes I am sure you are correct I just don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

So I am thinking something like as follows. Two things, without the actual total HTML, I am unsure of:

1) Does  `html.getElementsByTagName("td")` return a populated collection containing the item of interest?

2) If it does, where can you find  "Sales current" ? Is it, in the InnerText? OuterText? InnerHTML ? You would need to inspect the singleElement value to determine this or have a better understanding of HTML than me.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
'Add tools > References  > HTML Object library and to MS XML
    Dim myURL As String
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument, http As New XMLHTTP60

    myURL = "" 'something here

    With http
        .Open "GET", myURL, False
        .Send
        html.body.innerHTML = .ResponseText
    End With

    Dim allElements As IHTMLElementCollection

    Set allElements = html.getElementsByTagName("td")

    Dim singleElement As IHTMLElement

    For Each singleElement In allElements

        If InStr(1, singleElement.outerText, "Sales current") > 0 Then
            singleElement.Click
            Exit Sub
        End If

    Next singleElement

End Sub
```

Comment: I have no idea if will work but as others chip in can refine. I don’t know whether nested td get picked up which is why I suggest checking collection is both set and has something in it. Then you need to look at the elements if captured and find where in that element (which property) the sales text is. I mentioned some possibilities and an html guru such as @omegastripes would be able to tell you straight off I am sure

Comment: I have run the sub ok, but unfortunately, it does not seem to click the Sales Current link/text. I do not know how to verify / test if 'html.getElementsByTagName("td")' returns a populated collection.

Comment: Do you know how to use the locals window and step through code with F8?

Comment: Yes, I have done that and html ,http, allElements,singleElement all say 'nothing'  under value at first and then go blank as the code is steped through.

Comment: This is kinda hard to debug at a distance. html and http for example should not go blank. They should become populated as you step into your code and after passing the    End With
. Can you verify empty at the next line after the end with?